# How to remove the city label in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, wms

I have a WMS layer like this:

```
var wms_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            'OpenLayers WMS',
            'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
            {layers: 'basic,clabel,ctylabel,statelabel', transparent: true},
            {isBaseLayer: false, opacity: .7}
            );
```

How do I remove `ctylabel` or `statelabel` from this WMS layer?

Comment: Are you the creator of the WMS?  If so, what GIS server is serving the data (e.g. MapServer, GeoServer, QGIS Server...etc)?

Comment: No I am not the creator of the WMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By changing your code to

```
var wms_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            'OpenLayers WMS',
            'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
            {layers: 'basic,clabel', transparent: true},
            {isBaseLayer: false, opacity: .7}
            );
```

Alternatively, if you have created the layer already and want to remove the labels later:

```
wms_layer.mergeNewParams({LAYERS: 'basic,clabel'});
```

Answer (score 2):

You remove those layers from the LAYERS parameter.

```
      var wms_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        'OpenLayers WMS',
        'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
        {layers: 'basic,clabel', transparent: true},
        {isBaseLayer: false, opacity: .7}
      );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just want to remove the labels on the fly. Not at the creation of that layer. When user interact with the map I want to add/remove some labels like ctylabel or statelabel. How to add or remove this on the fly?

Comment: So what exactly do you mean by on the fly? What is changing that triggers the layers/labels to show/hide? Once you answer that question you may want to change the visibility of the layer rather than removing it.